# Gremlin Python: Query a list and that returns key/value list

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I want to query a list and the query response must return to me which response of the list item.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3]

graph.V().has("cid", "value", P.within(a)).in_('o_f_c').out('o_f_c').values().toList()
```

The response of above query is:

```
[1232131, 4322334, 124334, 354454, 23423423]
```

The response which I want is:

```
[[1, [1232131, 4322334]], 
[2, [124334],
[3, [354454,23423423]]
```

I just dont want to do that in a for loop with python. Is it possible do with gremlin-python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to `group()` your results:

```
g.V().has("cid", "value", P.within(a)).
  group().
    by('cid').
    by(__.in_('o_f_c').out('o_f_c').values().fold()).
  toList()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I just changed the `by('cid')`  with `by('value')` and import the `from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __`.